Could the damaged Columbia have skipped off the atmosphere several times until it just fell straight down and survived?

Assuming they had known the extent of the damage.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

NASA did an extensive research on how could Columbia be saved if we knew of the damage.
Their solution was to send a rescue shuttle.
There are two reasons why skipping does not work:

Heatshield are designed for high intensity, short duration heat profiles.
With a longer, repeated exposure, the heat would at least partially transfer to the shuttle, and with limited/no way to radiate it out during the exoatmospheric phases.

Even moderate reduction of velocity will lower the perigee enough that the next reentry will be done at a steep, unsurvivable angle.



If you think about it, the best-case reduction you could get would be to make it the same as if the shuttle were deorbiting from more like 100km instead of 370km.  Which immediately runs into two problems:  1.  It's probably still not enough, and 2. even with use of aerobraking, you're still also going to need a lot more fuel for the main engine than they're likely to have at the end of any particular mission.

No matter how the shuttle de-orbits, there's probably no significant change in the overall amount of kinetic energy that needs to be dissipated in any reentry scenario.  With that amount of energy that needs to be dissipated no matter what, the only way to prevent the loss would be to completely protect the damaged area from the brunt of reentry (and do a lot of praying), and that would be to reposition the shuttle during reentry to protect that leading wing edge.  (cont in next comment...)

cont... But that would put a completely different set of heat tiles and aerodynamic profile into the brunt of the reentry, which I'm sure would be a non-stable orientation, leading to other areas overheating compared to expected temperatures, or complete and sudden breakup due to unexpected mechanical and aerodynamic stresses.

@Milwrdfan There is one other way to do it: Send up another spacecraft (e.g. another Space Shuttle back then) with replacement heat tiles and replace the tiles on orbit before leaving the ISS. Or just give up on Columbia, leave the crew on the ISS, and have Columbia fly itself on some trajectory that would result in its destruction over a remote ocean area.

"Their solution was to send a rescue shuttle" - While this is discussed in Appendix D.13 of the official report (https://web.archive.org/web/20120921163712if_/http://govinfo.library.unt.edu/caib/news/report/pdf/vol2/part13.pdf), they seemed very sceptical that it could succeed - "the total risk of shortening training and preparation time is higher than the individual elements.", "There would be a number of activities that would be attempted for the first time during this conceptual inspection and rescue mission.", and other quotes including all of section 3.15 indicate that this 1/

was unlikely to succeed and would have put the rescue shuttle's crew in danger as well.

@reirab, based on final evidence, the damage was not just some missing tiles - most likely the wing structure leading edge had been damaged, so would have required a replacement/repair of the underlying leading edge of the wing to even provide support for heat tiles.  I doubt that could even have been done in orbit, no matter the amount of planning that could have been done or how much time they had to plan for such a repair attempt.

In this case, steep unsurvivable doesn't mean overwhelms the heat shield, it means exceeds the maximum gee tolerances of the shuttle; a breakup is inevitable.

@reirab iss was unreachable, on a different orbit for that particular mission.

@Antzi Ah, I had forgotten that that mission didn't visit the ISS.

I am not an expert on the Space Shuttle program so if anyone else could confirm this for me that would be nice and I could make this more certain; as far as I’m aware the issue with the Columbia orbiter was that there was some damage to the wing that caused reentry disintegration.
In any case there was damage to the spacecraft that meant that reentry would probably be catastrophic. Trying to aerobrake over several orbits would be dangerous (but not as dangerous as just straight-up deorbiting), and it wouldn’t bleed off enough velocity. At Columbia’s orbit, if a significant amount of velocity were lost, i.e. through skipping/aerobraking, the periapsis would end up being so low that it would just result in a full reentry in the next pass (if this weren’t the case, that is if the aerobrake didn’t bleed enough velocity to make that happen, then it also wouldn’t be consequential at all and it would have been a risk taken for no reason). Simple terms: there wasn’t a safe way to reduce velocity by aerobraking at that orbit and without a fully-functional spacecraft.

Assuming they had known the extent of the damage.

That’s the other issue. Any kind of non-standard aerobrake or deorbit would have been seen as a huge risk, which of course might have been slightly less-risky than a straight deorbit, but they didn’t know the extent of the damage at the time (I don’t think; again I’m not a 100% expert here), so even if someone did identify that there was potentially-fatal damage, they couldn’t be sure and it would certainly have seemed safer to follow protocol and deorbit as normal than try something exotic to deorbit without an understanding of the damage that had taken place.
I can’t think of a regular reentry position that wouldn’t result in failure. With a flaw in the wing that section would have to be away from aero forces, but if the orbiter is off-angle at all then there’ll be non-shielded parts exposed to those forces, and that definitely would be catastrophic.

No, it is not a NASA simulation, but I just tried this in Kerbal Space Program with Real Solar System and RP-1 installed along with a couple other aerodynamics realism mods. It did not work.
I simulated the damaged shuttle with a zero-mass non-heatshielded part embedded in the wing and assumed that if it blew up for any reason that would be catastrophic (this would be real-world equivalent of what happened - disintegration). Without the flaw it worked fine and deorbiting was great but with the part there was always catastrophe on the final reentry. I tried skipping off the atmosphere a couple times for some aerobraking and I wasn’t able to get more than two aerobrakes in before I was on a suborbital trajectory; I always ended up having too much speed for the flawed wing to survive. Final conclusion: no matter how much aerobraking went down, the damage to the wing made it impossible to survive the atmosphere at reentry speeds.

I wish I could give you two upvotes for trying it in KSP!

Obligatory XKCD
